# Change IDENTITY_INSERT to ON in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, insert, identity

How can I insert an `ID` into an identity column in SQL Server? I'll make a special item into my table and I will quickly detect that item by the `ID`. So because all other ID's are bigger or equal to one, I will give that special item the ID zero.

The problem is now, when I've created that table I've place the identity of the column ID on true. If I insert now the special item with code below, I've got next error:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(ID, Name, Description) 
VALUES (0, 'Special title', 'special item');
```

Error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table `MyTable` when `IDENTITY_INSERT` is set to `OFF`.

How can I change this table, column or property so I can create a record with ID zero?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Explicit identity insert require `IDENTITY_INSERT` property set to ON.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON  -- Statement Allows explicit values to be inserted into 
                                -- the identity column of a table.
GO

INSERT INTO MyTable(ID, Name, Description) 
VALUES (0, 'Special title', 'special item');
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF  -- Statement revert granted permission
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

USE `SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLEnAME ON`

Remember to turn off identity and that only one table can have identity_insert On at one time